# Select through list items populated by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple list item

```
        <ul class="nav" ng-repeat="mainBrandName in allBrands">
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="goSubBrand(mainBrandName.brand, mainBrandName.subbrands[0].name)">
            Selected Brand Name = {{mainBrandName.brand}}
            </a></li>
        </ul>
```

which list some brand names and on each link i have a function onclick which populate another sub set of brands, and it works fine.

but here i want a navigation like this

```
        <ul class="nav" ng-repeat="mainBrandName in allBrands">
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="goSubBrand(mainBrandName.brand, mainBrandName.subbrands[0].name)">
            Selected Brand Name = {{mainBrandName.brand}}
            </a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" ng-click="next()">Next</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="previous()">Previous</a>
```

so that instead of clicking on each list item i can select through by clicking next and previous(also i need to run the function on selection change).

please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is not very clear what youre trying to achieve, a plunker or fiddle will help, but if i get you, you want your navigation links simulate the click of the next and previous sub-brands links, you can use something like this to make it work:

```
$scope.goSubBrand = function(brand, sub){ 'Your logic here' }

$scope.allBrands = [{brand: 'brand 1', subbrands: [{name: 'subbrand 1'},{...}]}, {brand: 'brand 2',....}];
$scope.selected = {brand: 0, subbrand: 1};

$scope.next = function(){
    if(typeof allBrands[$scope.selected.brand].subbrands[$scope.selected.brand+1] != 'undefined'){
        $scope.selected.subbrand++; //go to next subbrand
    } else {
        $scope.selected.subbrand = 0; //return to first sub brand if last reached
    }
};
$scope.previous = function() { 
    if(typeof allBrands[$scope.selected.brand].subbrands[$scope.selected.brand-1] != 'undefined'){
        $scope.selected.subbrand--; //go to previous subbrand
    } else {
        $scope.selected.subbrand =  $scope.allBrands[$scope.selected.brand].subbrands.length - 1; //go to last if first reached
    }
};
//trigger the method $scope.goSubBrand on any change of the $scope.selected object
$scope.$watchCollection('selected', function(){ 
    var sel = $scope.allBrands[$scope.selected.brand];
    $scope.goSubBrand(sel.brand, sel.subbrands[$scope.selected.subbrand].name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks strife86, i am new to angular, here i made a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hareeshmh/zporpfwf/)

Comment: ok i see you display the info of the selected brand and down bellow  the info of the selected subbrand, but whats the exact behaviour youre trying to achieve wit your nav buttons?

Comment: ![image](http://pixelcrafts.com/soo/soo-products-popup.jpg). This is what i am trying to achieve, you can see the main brands at left bottom with two up&down arrows.

Comment: the modification of my code should work for you, just need to make the up and down functions but changing the $scope.selected.brand that way it any chanche of the selected object will trigger your goSubBrand method

Comment: Strife86, i am slowly trying to do it in your way, here is what i did so far[Test link](http://pixelcrafts.com/soo/test/index.html), but when click on next getting an error  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined** at the end section of your code `$scope.goSubBrand(sel.brand, sel.subbrands[$scope.selected.subbrand].name);` you can see it with developer tools. Thanks for your time.

Comment: i fork your code in a plnkr it seems to be working by now next, previous, up and down check it [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bZd3RIMBycAqw8bf1ll?p=preview)